# Cannot understand the grammatical relation between two comma-separated phrases

Tags: grammaticality, subordinate-clause

**Q:** What is the grammatical relationship between the italicized phrase and the one that precedes it?

> Dabei lag das Decken von Staatsausgaben über die Notenpresse durchaus im allgemeinen Zeitgeist, *die Zentralbank stärker unter die Kontrolle der Regierung zu bringen und die Geldpolitik eher auf konjunkturelle Ziele und weniger auf den Erhalt der Preisstabilität auszurichten*.

**Q:** In particular, is the italicized phrase qualifying *Zeitgeist*?

It would be slightly less confusing (although still unusual-looking) if the sentence were

> Dabei lag durchaus im allgemeinen Zeitgeist, *die Zentralbank stärker unter die Kontrolle der Regierung zu bringen und die Geldpolitik eher auf konjunkturelle Ziele und weniger auf den Erhalt der Preisstabilität auszurichten*.

...which I would interpret as an inversion of

> Dabei lag *die Zentralbank stärker unter die Kontrolle der Regierung zu bringen und die Geldpolitik eher auf konjunkturelle Ziele und weniger auf den Erhalt der Preisstabilität auszurichten* durchaus im allgemeinen Zeitgeist.

The reason I find the latter sentence easier to rationalize is that it maps more readily to the following structure in English,

> Nevertheless, **to bring** the central bank more firmly under the government's control and **[to] direct** the monetary policy more towards economic goals and less towards maintaining price stability were entirely within the general spirit of the times.

**Q:** Are the alternatives above even grammatical?

At any rate, they are saying something different from what the original says (since they say nothing about the covering of the state's expenditures through the printing of money).

---

In case it helps answer my question, here's the full context:

> <sup>Die 1950er und der Anfang der 1960er Jahre waren jedenfalls von einer monetären und wirtschaftlichen Stabilität geprägt, die nichts mit dem Chaos der Zeit nach dem Ersten Weltkrieg gemein hatte.  Trotzdem wies das Bretton-Woods-System von Anfang an auch Konstruktionsfehler auf, die hauptsächlich aus der Sonderstellung des US-Dollars resultierten.  So konnte bei einer gegebenen Menge an Gold eine weltweite Erhöhung der Geldnachfrage, die sich bei wachsenden Wirtschaften automatisch ergibt, nur über eine zusätzliche Emittierung von US-Dollars befriedigt werden.  Langfristig sollte dies jedoch das Vertrauen in die Einlösepﬂicht der amerikanischen Zentralbank, des Federal Reserve Systems, von 35 $ pro Unze Gold untergraben.  Dieser Widerspruch, der auch unter dem Begriff des Trifﬁn Dilemmas14 bekannt geworden ist, verschärfte sich mit der expansiven Geldpolitik, welche Amerika betrieb, um unter anderem den Vietnamkrieg und das großangelegte Reformprogramm der „Great Society“ mitzuﬁnanzieren.  **Dabei lag das Decken von Staatsausgaben über die Notenpresse durchaus im allgemeinen Zeitgeist, *die Zentralbank stärker unter die Kontrolle der Regierung zu bringen und die Geldpolitik eher auf konjunkturelle Ziele und weniger auf den Erhalt der Preisstabilität auszurichten*.**</sup>

Comment: Your counterexamples all lack an *es* after *lag*. That's the item *das Decken…* in the original sentence. You cannot omit the *es*.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: I edited my post to make my questions more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case a grammatical term is needed: the italicized phrase is commonly referred to as **attributiver Infinitiv**.

*Attributiv* means *modifying a noun*:

> **konjunkturelle** Ziele *(attributives Adjektiv)*
> das Problem, **dass nicht alle Schüler einen Laptop haben** *(attributiver Nebensatz)*

*Infinitiv* is a lazy way of saying *satzwertige Infinitivkonstruktion*, *satzwertiger zu-Infinitiv* (or similar).

> die Idee, **sich selbständig zu machen**
> seine Art, **sich zu kleiden**
> der Wunsch, **die Welt zu verändern**
> der Gedanke, **bald wieder arbeiten zu müssen**

The alternatives you provide turn the infinitive from a phrase modifying a noun into a subject (**Subjektsinfinitiv**). In the original sentence, *das Decken von Staatsausgaben über die Notenpresse* is the subject.

Answer (score 2):

1. & 2. Yes, the italicized parts are qualifying *Zeitgeist*.
2. The alternatives are grammatical, but one lacks an expletive *es*:

> Dabei lag **es** durchaus im allgemeinen Zeitgeist, die Zentralbank stärker unter die Kontrolle der Regierung zu bringen und die Geldpolitik eher auf konjunkturelle Ziele und weniger auf den Erhalt der Preisstabilität auszurichten.

and the other one lacks some commas:

> Dabei lag, die Zentralbank stärker unter die Kontrolle der Regierung zu bringen und die Geldpolitik eher auf konjunkturelle Ziele und weniger auf den Erhalt der Preisstabilität auszurichten, durchaus im allgemeinen Zeitgeist.

Comment: Just as an addition regarding 2.: these hints are both recommended but not obligtatory. The "es" can be ommitted, and the Commas around an extended infinitve haven't been obligatory any more since the Rechtschreibreform.

Comment: @HalvarF Thanks, I did not know that.